# Does Yuan-Ti Magic Resistance provide advantage for concentration saving throws, where spell damage was the cause?

Tags: dnd-5e, saving-throw, racial-traits, concentration, yuan-ti

The [Yuan-ti Pureblood](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/yuan-ti-pureblood)'s Magic Resistance racial trait (VGtM, p. 120) provides:

> advantage on saving throws against spells and other magical effects

I'm clear on that.

If I'm concentrating on a spell and take damage, I need to do a Constitution saving throw to see if the damage breaks my concentration.

**Does the Yuan-ti racial ability allow me to do this saving throw with advantage if the damage was spell/magical?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### No

The Constitution saving throw to maintain concentration is caused by the damage - not the effect that caused the damage.

Similarly, your death saving throws wouldn’t have advantage if the damage that dropped you to 0hp came from one of these sources.

Comment: It might be even clearer to add that the purpose of the Constitution saving throw is to maintain concentration, so it's not a saving throw "against a spell or other magical effect"; it's just a saving throw to maintain concentration.